# Angular Interpolation: Is less performance get/set that simple attribute?

Tags: angular, performance

Hi if I have a model like that:

```
export class MyObj{
    public first='hi';
    private _second='world';

    public get second(){
        console.log('called');
        return this._second;
    }
    ... set ...
}
```

and use that in this way in html:

```
{{obj.first}}{{obj.second}}
```

I can see in console that get function it's called a lot of time (for change detection cycle).

Excluding the fact that call a function it's a little more complex that access direct to attribute My question is: Angular "call"(read) a lot of time also the "simple" attribute as it does for the get function or when Angular finds a get function it has a different behavior that decreasing a lot the performance?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is, it is happening because of angular change detection. Angular periodically checks if any of the values, bound to a template, changed, and if so updates the necessary value in the view.

if you want to bind simple attributes you should not use a function to get the values, just declaraing them would do.

Regarding the performance, certainly there is a performance issue when you use function call in the templates and just bind a variable.

Comment: Yes i know that. But i asked if there is performance difference between the two approach.

Comment: me too i removed the "probably" in "for change detection"

Comment: @Sajeetharan do pipes work similarly to functions? I mean are they called every time during change detection cycles even though the original value does not change?

Comment: so and so.. because is normal that call a function (also if return only a simple value without any other logic) is less performance but i don't understand if Angular maybe apply some skip strategy for simple attribute (like it does for pipe) or it's exactly the same in strategy.
thanks for answer.

Comment: yeah, thats why using pipe is not recommended

Comment: @Ploppy @ sajeetharan i read that with pipe there is a cache system that prevent useless call https://blog.oasisdigital.com/2017/angular-runtime-performance-guide/

Comment: @Alessandro true pipes are optimised and safe to use, what you should NOT use is bind to function calls (eg: `<div>{{getMyValue()}}</div>`)